# Get an access token

Tags: nest-device-access

I tried to get an access token with the google documentation.

> curl -L -X POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?
> client_id=oauth2-client-id& client_secret=oauth2-client-secret&
> code=authorization-code& grant_type=authorization_code&
> redirect_uri=https://www.google.com'

With this request it didn't worked.
I added `-H 'Content-Length: 0'` and now I'm ending up with

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fixing the space didn't work, re-do you linking here [from the Google guide](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#link_your_account), steps 1-6. Then get a new authorization code. I had the same issue and re-linking worked for me (with the -H flag).

Comment: sorry, but that link is apparently related to NEST; what's the URL for step 1 to get an authorization code for a regular Google (NOT NEST) API?

Comment: There might be API specific documentation, but here is the general [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have a space in the request:
`/v4/token? client_id=oauth2-client-id`
when i tried to copy past the commands from the documentation it didn't work.
i had to re-edit the request before i could use it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.

```
curl -L -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id=<client_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=<secret>&code=4/4wGANiKF5......N0Jg&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com"
```

Stumped

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to use a different redirect_uri? Your own configured redirect uri?

Comment: I thought so, but tried that also and makes no difference